# How to add a drag and drop feature in Excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, drag-and-drop

How do I add a 'drag and drop' feature in excel so that if I drag a thumbnail for pdf, word, spreadsheet, etc to the cell, it saves the document to a designated location and displays a hyperlink within the cell to the saved location or automatically opens when clicked

Comment: What have you tried? You should post any code you have tried to accomplish this task.

Comment: @MichaelZ. Maybe they did post the code of what they have TRIED ;)

Comment: @ForwardEd It does sound like an interesting feature though, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does.  The easier approach it normally an import button and go find the file.  I think you would need to define a landing  pad for the drag an drop.  work in some way to distinguish drag and drop of a file versus drag and drop of some text from another document.  Very easy question to ask, lots and lots of coding to implement.

Comment: @ForwardEd It's not that difficult to copy the file where you want it then in Windows Explorer hold the `Shift` key when right clicking on the file. This will give you a menu item to copy the path of the file. Then paste that value into the Excel sheet.

Comment: I feel like this what the OP wants would have to have all kinds of checks. What if the user deletes the value from Excel. Does the file stick around?

Comment: @ForwardEd alright, I admit it...I'm an accountant and trying to learn enough to find a way to add this feature but I can't find any step by step instructions with google searches. I was told to try posting here.

Comment: @Forwarded that's easy to copy the info but the feature I'm hoping for is to have a column of 100's of documents being housed. the drag and drop feature I was hoping to have pasted in every cell of the column.  I want people that are EVEN less tech savvy than myself to be able to use the spreadsheet to 'grab' their documents from excel when they need them.

Comment: @Jake oh cool, another fellow accountant. What you're asking is very code intensive. No one is going to do it for you for free. Please hire someone.

Comment: I think you'd have a much easier time writing the code in .net for a .net Excel addin.

Comment: @Jake try this link to get you started https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840032(v=office.12).aspx